Ubuntu 22.04.3 black screen after Grub selection on read-only flash drive
Booting Ubuntu read-only using overlayroot.
Ubuntu boots as expected but when I turn on write-protection on Kanguru Solutions WP-KFT3-32G flash drive, boot hangs on black screen after Grub selection.
Same happens on NVMe disk when disk is set to read-only using sedutil-cli (via TCG OPAL 2.00 standard)
Would anyone happen to know why?
